# Sequentially add rows according to shared variable

Tags: r

I have got a `reference` table that contains a list of samples, together with several values that have already been added to the table (here: `Value1`) :

```
reference <- data.frame(sample=letters[1:5], Value1=1:5)

> reference
  sample Value1
1      a      1
2      b      2
3      c      3
4      d      4
5      e      5
```

To this table, I need to add other data (here: `Value2` to `Value4`) that belong to the individual samples (data from each sample = `myinput`:

```
myinput_a <- data.frame(sample="a", Value2=3, Value3=5, Value4=9)

myinput_a
  sample Value2 Value3 Value4
1      a      3      5      9

myinput_b <- data.frame(sample="b", Value2=5, Value3=0, Value4=2)
myinput_c <- data.frame(sample="c", Value2=7, Value3=1, Value4=3)
```

These myinputs share the `sample`  variable with `reference`, so they must be appended to the correct row.

This is the desired end result (note that d and e weren't added, so there are some `NA` values:

````
myoutput <- data.frame(sample=letters[1:5], Value1=1:5, Value2=c(3,5,7,NA,NA), Value3=c(5,0,1,NA,NA), Value4=c(9,2,3,NA,NA))``` 

> myoutput
  sample Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
1      a      1      3      5      9
2      b      2      5      0      2
3      c      3      7      1      3
4      d      4     NA     NA     NA
5      e      5     NA     NA     NA
````

In reality, the number of samples and values is very large, so I would like to design the whole thing as a loop. The part I can't figure out is that when adding the first sample, I'm appending columns, whereas with all subsequent samples, I'm adding rows. I'm grateful for any advice on how to design the approach!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind you input dataframes by row using e.g. `rbind`, then join to your reference dataframe using e.g. `merge`:

```r
myinput <- rbind(myinput_a, myinput_b, myinput_c)

merge(reference, myinput, by = "sample", all.x = TRUE)
#>   sample Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
#> 1      a      1      3      5      9
#> 2      b      2      5      0      2
#> 3      c      3      7      1      3
#> 4      d      4     NA     NA     NA
#> 5      e      5     NA     NA     NA
```

or using `dpylr` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
myinput <- bind_rows(myinput_a, myinput_b, myinput_c)

left_join(reference, myinput, by = "sample")
#>   sample Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
#> 1      a      1      3      5      9
#> 2      b      2      5      0      2
#> 3      c      3      7      1      3
#> 4      d      4     NA     NA     NA
#> 5      e      5     NA     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

One more base R solution using `cbind`:

```
df <- rbind(myinput_a, myinput_b, myinput_c)
x <- nrow(df)
y <- nrow(reference)

df[x+(y-x),] <- NA
cbind(reference, df[-1])

sample Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
1      a      1      3      5      9
2      b      2      5      0      2
3      c      3      7      1      3
4      d      4     NA     NA     NA
5      e      5     NA     NA     NA
```